# For $P$ a non constant polynomial, if $[a, b]$ contains no critical points of $P$, can we determine $P^{-1}([a, b])$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, polynomials

Let be $P \in \mathbb{C}[X]$ a non constant polynomial.

I'll use the notation $P^{-1}$ for the preimage.

If $[a, b]$ ($a, b \in \mathbb{R}$) contains no critical points of $P$, can we have information on $P^{-1}([a, b])$ more than:

- it is closed by continuity ;
- it is bounded (because $\lim_{\lvert z\vert \to +\infty} P(z) = \pm \infty$)
- then, it's compact ;

My intuition is: it's some reunion related to the polynomial $P$, but unsure.

Comment: @Macavity P = X, take any interval [a, b], as P' is constant, there is no critical point at all, and indeed, P^-1([a, b]) is the reunion of one interval, itself? Was this your question?

Comment: Let $P=-X^2$.  Now what did you mean by $P^{-1}([1,2])$, say?

Comment: @Macavity Apparently, the OP works in $\Bbb C$, so that would be $[i,\sqrt 2i]\cup [-i,-\sqrt 2i]$, I suppose.

Comment: @Macavity In general, for $f : E \to F$ a map and a set $K \subset F$, $f^{-1}(K) = \{ x \in E \mid f(x) \in K \}$

Comment: Thanks. OK - that’s clearer now. It need not even be connected, but is a union of intervals in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @Macavity Have you a proof of this result?

Comment: What are $a,b$, real numbers?

Comment: @MarcBogaerts Yes